# Determining Bundt pan size when recipe gives a loaf tin size

Tags: cake

What size Bundt pan do I need for a pound cake that is supposed to be baked in a 9 by 5 loaf tin ? I have a Bundt pan (never used one before) that holds 8 cups of water.

Answer (score 4):

According to here, your 8 cup Bundt pan should work.

https://cooksinfo.com/baking-pans-by-volume